# When will update view after set layout parameter in Android

Tags: android, invalidation

I write some codes like bellow in my custom view.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
lp.setMargins(100, 100, 0 ,0);
lp.width = 200;
lp.height = 200;
```

I use break point at last line and found value of getX() is still 0 in evaluate expression window.

I want to know when will update value of getX() after set layout parameter, it should be 100.

Thanks.

Comment: did you set it to some view like button1.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: Yes i set, but i've tried either setLayoutParams or not are no different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `LayoutParams` for a child view, its parent will do measure phase and layout phase again.

Your code `setLayoutParams()` will be added to MessageQueue to execute. You use break point here won't see anything.

To get new `LayoutParams`, you should post a message like this

```
yourView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.getX();
            }
        });
```

Another way:

```
yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // get your view size here
            }
        });
```

If you want to see whenever your view update it LayoutParams, insert log inside `layout()` method of your custom View

```
@Override
public void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    Log.d("alex.hong", "before X = " + getX());

    super.layout(l, t, r, b);

    Log.d("alex.hong", "current X = " + getX());
}
```